# Is there any way to generate MS Build from n existing C# project in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, selenium-webdriver

I am new to the .Net world I am trying to do some continuous delivery on a project of **NUnit** tests written in C# , these tests run fine on the Visual Studio, but I want to build it using MsBuild and, if I am not wrong, does it need an XML? In the Java world Eclipse would generate an a build.xml.

Can we generate a XML using VS? If yes how ? 
I am using VS Professional 2012 with Re-sharper if that helps.

Comment: It is always built by MSBuild, nothing you could do to stop that.  The IDE uses it as well, the solution and project files are already good as-is.

Comment: You should also look into [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs). It is free for up to five users, and cheap after that. It includes CI builds.

Comment: WE use TeamCity for CI and it asks for Build file path: . What should this field be in that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution (`sln`) or the Project (`csproj`) files are *already* XML-Based Visual Studio items that the MSBuild knows how to handle properly - Internally, visual studio using the MSBuild utility.

In order to locate these files, a common path to find them would be:

At the solution folder you'll find the `.sln` file and in each sub-folder you supposed to find the corresponded `.csproj` file.

Comment: A .sln is actually no MsBuild file,  but MsBuild will  convert it to a XML proj file on build.

Comment: TeamCity asks for  a Build file path: ..\De.. What part of a project should I associate here